# Rows/Columns JavaScript DHTML

Tags: javascript, dhtml

I am looking to have a function, that when pressing a button, the function generates rows/colums.

I've been trying with the following code

```
 function addTRTD(){ 
 var tbElm = document.getElementById("tbdy");

 var newRow = document.createElement("tr");

 var newCol1= document.createElement("TD");
 var newCol2= document.createElement("TD");


 newCol1.innerHTML = "Row 1 Cell 1";
 newCol2.innerHTML = "Row 1 Cell 2";;


 newRow.appendChild(newCol1);
     newRow.appendChild(newCol2);


 tbElm.appendChild(newRow);


     newCol1.innerHTML = "Row 1 Cell 1";
     newCol2.innerHTML = "Row 1 Cell 1";



     var newRow = document.createElement("tr");
     newRow.appendChild(newCol1);
     newRow.appendChild(newCol2);

     var newCol1= document.createElement("TD");
     var newCol2= document.createElement("TD");

     newCol1.innerHTML = "Row 2 Cell 1";
     newCol2.innerHTML = "Row 2 Cell 2";


 tbElm.appendChild(newRow);
 }
```

but no luck. Clicking on the button I just get the following output
       Row 1 Cell 1 Row 1 Cell 2

how can I get to display information of Row2?

Comment: What is `newText` and `newText2`?

Comment: Something you might want to look into with working with tables is `insertRow` and `insertCell` methods

Comment: sorry for confusing, newText and newText2 are other variables i have declared on the function - in effort to reduce the number of lines on my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Auto-Gen</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

var template = '</table>\
<div align="justify">\
<td>\
<select name="name{num}" title="25">\
<option value="1">1</option>\
<option value="2">2</option>\
<option value="3">3</option>\
<option value="4">4</option>\
<option value="5">5</option>\
<option value="6">6</option>\
<option value="7">7</option>\
<option value="8">8</option>\
<option value="9">9</option>\
<option value="10">10</option>\
<option value="11">11</option>\
<option value="12">12</option>\
<option value="13">13</option>\
<option value="14">14</option>\
<option value="15">15</option>\
<option value="16">16</option>\
<option value="17">17</option>\
<option value="18">18</option>\
<option value="19">19</option>\
<option value="20">20</option>\
<option value="21">21</option>\
<option value="22">22</option>\
<option value="23">23</option>\
<option value="24">24</option>\
<option value="25">25</option>\
<option value="26">26</option>\
<option value="27">27</option>\
<option value="28">28</option>\
<option value="29">29</option>\
<option value="30" selected="selected">30</option>\
<option value="31">31</option>\
<option value="32">32</option>\
</select>\
</td>\
<td>\
    {num}\
 </td>\
</div>';

var counter =0;

function addNew() {
    a = document.createElement('div');
    html = template.replace(/{num}/g, counter.toString());
    a.innerHTML = html;
    var mainContainer = document.getElementById('mainContainer');
    mainContainer.appendChild(a);
    counter++;
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="mainContainer"> </div>

<div align="justify"> <input value="Add" onclick="addNew()" type="button"> </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you very much everyone for your comments and help

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i'm following your code, because it looks like you have one row with two columns, but then declare a row with 5 columns.

If you have consistent rows, i have found in the past that the easiest thing to do is create a hidden row that will act as the template.  this also allows any styling you have created dynamically to be applied.

than you can just do something like 
var newRow = $('table.templaterow').clone();
than set each of the columns: newRow.find('td')

than append to the table.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, however i just feel that for the script i am trying to accomplish cloning the row will complicae my life :)